# Запекание (Noise Texture + BSDF) в Image Texture

Tags: blender

Доброе утро, столкнулся с проблемой при запекании в Image Texture. Еще слабо понимаю нюансы, поэтому не могу понять в какую сторону лезть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, большинство примитивных вещей запекается методом Diffuse. Однако у меня конкретно в этом случае с этим шейдингом запекшаяся текстура просто белая, хотя объект я выбрал. Подходит ли тип Diffuse для такого запекания?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Окей, для всех, кто столкнется с похожей проблемой и не будет понимать, в какую сторону копать. Оказывается метод запекания Diffuse работает с полем Base Color в BSDF ноде. У меня в примере Noise Texture был подключен в Subsurface. Иными словами, в моем случае такой тип запекания просто не подходит. А так как в Base Color ничего не подключено, то и текстура была по сути пустой после бейкинга.